# css wrap and fill rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

How can I tell CSS to wrap such that when there are two rows, each row contains half the content; three rows: a third of the content; four rows: a quarter; etc.?  Alternatively, if I have a fixed number of elements (let's say 4), can I tell CSS to prefer to break a line at half the contents, before breaking at the first overflow?

**EDIT:** there are other elements on the screen (width-wise), so please don't suggest something that relies on screen width.  also, i don't know at what pixel width the labels will wrap.  is there a way to find out?

Preferred breaks in the code below:

```
// Wide enough for everything
Bedrooms: 1 2 3 4

// A little less than that
Bedrooms: 1 2
          3 4

// Not wide enough for text and half the checkboxes
Bedrooms:
1 2 3 4

// Not wide enough for the checkboxes
// In case the checkboxes are wider than the text
Bedrooms:
   1 2
   3 4

// Not wide enough for two checkboxes
// In case two checkboxes are wider than the text
Bedrooms:
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/HfuRL/

CSS:

```css
/*horizontal the jquery mobile 1.4.2 way removes icons, so hack it in*/
.horizontal-with-icons .ui-checkbox {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <form style="display: table; margin: 0px auto;">
            <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">Bedrooms:</div>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="horizontal-with-icons" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-1" type="checkbox" />1</label>
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-2" type="checkbox" />2</label>
                <!--TODO: wrap here-->
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-3" type="checkbox" />3</label>
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-4" type="checkbox" />4</label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using a grid framework.  here are a bunch.  http://mashable.com/2013/04/26/css-boilerplates-frameworks/

Comment: @skzryzg Why use grids for such a small thing?

Comment: Well, the behavior @Jayden describes is precisely what grid frameworks were created for, and there's no need to reinvent the wheel.  And while the specific scenario is a simple case, s/he is clearly planning a page that is responsive, so anything applied to this singular case will also apply to the page as a whole. finally Jayden seems unaware of grid frameworks. and even if you dont agree with their usage, it's at least good to be aware of their existence

Comment: you may need a JS solution for this. I'm not sure whether it is possible to achieve it using CSS only. Note that if you manually split contorlgroup element, you'll lose styles.

Comment: @skzryzg can i use grids without a framework?  i see there's a thing called css grid layouts, and there's a polyfill available for "IE9+ and all other browsers"

Comment: @skzryzg i started looking at the grid frameworks.  there's a lot!  can you point me to an example that does what i want?  i'm having trouble finding one (mostly because i don't really know what i'm looking at.)

Comment: @jayden, I just got to work, but when I get a chance I'll try to find a simple one that fits your needs

Comment: if you still want to use grids, use [jQM grid system](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/grids/). However, it won't give the desired result if you combine it with controlgroup.

Comment: everything i find relies on screen width, and in pixels.  there's no way to be smarter?  like using computed width/wrapping?

Comment: smarter/responsive/dynamic = JS involved. it's up to you.

Comment: any pointers on what the JS might look like?